# Change keymap using .xinitrc

Tags: xmodmap

I have made a .xinitrc file in my home directory. Want to run the file xinit.rc form directory ${HOME}/bin/inge.

Is the following the way to do things?

File: .xinitrc

```
#!/bin/bash

source ${HOME}/bin/inge/xinit.rc
```

---

File: ${HOME}/bin/inge/xinit.rc

```
#!/bin/bash

linge_trk="${HOME}/bin/inge"

xmodmap_variant=2
if (( xmodmap_variant == 0 )); then
  xmodmap ${linge_trk}/inge-xmodmap
elif (( xmodmap_variant == 1 )); then
  xmodmap ${linge_trk}/camswap-xmodmap
else
  echo "Not using xmodmap"
fi
```

Comment: I suppose you want to set the keyboard layout as soon as the X server is started.
While your approach would work, it is overcomplicated.
Instead of using 4 different files, you can put all of your code into the `xinit.rc` file in the appropriate section of your `if` statement.

Comment: Note that your question is not about an actual problem and might get removed.


[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)
'your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”'

Comment: I am writing a configuration package, and users would simply link to the package, rather than transferring files.  The question is whether such method would work.  And whether the xinit.rc is just a bash script.

Comment: @mashuptwice I have different `xmodmap` files corresponding to different keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a folder in `~/bin/` you might want to put the specific filetypes in their [appropriate directories](https://linuxhandbook.com/linux-directory-structure/):

- `/etc` configuration files, in your case `inge-xmodmap` and `camswap-xmodmap`
- `/usr/bin` user binaries, in this case `somescript`

While you could name your script as you want, `xinit.rc` doesn't seem like an appropriate name as it could be easily confused with the `.xinitrc` file. For this reason I will use `somescript` for your scripts name.

You can modify your script to take an argument and call it with the argument from your `.xinitrc` file to set the appropriate keyboard layout. This also has the advantage that the script can be invoked manually easier.

**Example:**

```
#!/bin/bash

#keymap directory
somescript_configdir="/etc/somescript"

#command help
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || [ "$1" == "-h" ] || [ "$1" == "--help" ]; then
    echo -e "keymap helper script"
    echo -e "Usage: somescript [OPTION] VARIANT\n"
    echo -e "Parameter              Desciption\n"
    echo "-h, --help                show this help text"
    echo "-s,  --set                set keyboard mapping, requires VARIANT"
    exit 0
#parse arguments
elif ( [ -z "$2" ] && [ "$1" == "-s" ] ) || ( [ -z "$2" ] && [ "$1" == "--set" ] ); then
    echo "Error: setting the keyboard mapping requires VARIANT as argument!"
    exit 0
elif [ "$2" == "1" ] && ( [ "$1" == "-s" ]  || [ "$1" == "--set" ] ); then
    xmodmap "$somescript_configdir/inge-xmodmap"
elif [ "$2" == "2" ] && ( [ "$1" == "-s" ]  || [ "$1" == "--set" ] ); then
    xmodmap "$somescript_configdir/camswap-xmodmap"
fi
```

If `/usr/bin/` is in your `$PATH` you can change the keymap with `somescript -s 1`, which should also work if you put it in your `.xinitrc` file.

Comment: yes, call it with an argument would be much clear what is being done.